# i have an erro with Sql data insertion

Tags: mysql, sql

```
'$email'";
    $result = $this->selectQuery($sql);
return $result[0]->Id;
}

function insertTestUser($insertData) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_akl_insert VALUES (" . $insertData . ")";
    $insertAction = parent::insertQuery($sql);
    return $insertAction;
}
```

here i have an error in data insertion. and my error is here:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1)' at line 1
```

please help me any body!!!!

Comment: Can you post more of your code? What comes before this: `'$email'";
    $result = $this->selectQuery($sql);
return $result[0]->Id;
}`?

Comment: Is `$insertData` a number? Either way, use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my SQL server version you must insert the values inside quotes, i.e.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_akl_insert VALUES ('" . $value_field_1 . "','".$value_field_2."','"......"')";
```

Comment: if value to be inserted is number then it is okay to not enclose in quotes

Comment: The above code doesn't have value validation.... so basically if $insertData includes a " the query will fail, it is required to convert it to \"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `$insertData` is properly formatted. As in, escape the quotes if you're inserting text, and also comma separate all the data.

A typical insert statement looks like this:

`INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(1, 2, "three", 4);`

So your `$insertData` needs to look like this:

`$insertData = '1, 2, \"three\", 4';`

Also, as you can see from the colouring of the code here on SO, you're missing a closing quote from the first bit of your code:

```
'$email'";
    $result = $this->selectQuery($sql);
    return $result[0]->Id;
}
```

The double quote in the first line doesn't have a corresponding closing one.